# VSCode Python autocompletion not working on some classes only

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When using autocompletion in VSCode in my python project, it works very well except for one class and I cannot figure out why.

The class is coming from a module `database` which contains 3 classes total: `DatabaseClient`, `Database`, `Collection`

`DatabaseClient` has a `get_database()` method which returns a `Database` object.
`Database` has a `get_collection()` method which returns a `Collection` object.
`Collection` has several methods.

The autocompletion works as intended on the `DatabaseClient` & `Database` objects, but not at all on the `Collection` object.

The code below works and give the expected results (line 15 and 20 of the screenshot results match), but not the autocompletion while editing as stated above.

```py
import lib.database as database

print( database.DatabaseClient().get_database('business').get_collection('reviews').find() )

client = database.DatabaseClient()
db = client.get_database(client.list_database_names()[0])
coll = db.get_collection(db.list_collection_names()[0])
print(coll.find())
```

[image: VSCode Python inconsistent autocompletion]

Tried to reload VSCode, unload and reload the python extensions.
Tried to uninstall and re-install the python extensions.
Tried to change the name of my module.
Tried to change the name of the class.
Tried to change the name of the method of the `Collection` class.
Tried using single line command line 3 and noticed it worked this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution.
The problem comes from not using typing in the method headers.
Once I added proper typing, the autocompletion worked everywhere as expected.

```py
def get_database(self, database_name: str) -> Database:
```

```py
def get_collection(self, collection_name: str) -> Collection:
```